# Android API CellInfo & CellInfoGsm

Tags: android

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfoGsm.html)

I would like to get CellInfoGsm data, but I got some error.

CellInfoGsm is subclass of CellInfo. I don't know how to get the CellInfoGsm data.

Could someone help me to write the right code?

```
TelephonyManager TM = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

(CellInfoGsm) cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)TM.getAllCellInfo();
```

Comment: I got the error message in (CellInfoGsm) cellingsm this Line.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - cellinfogsm cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Cannot cast from List<CellInfo> to CellInfoGsm
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Cannot cast from List<CellInfo> to CellInfoGsm
 - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
  Assignment
 - CellInfoGsm cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code.

- `(CellInfoGsm) cellinfogsm` needs to be changed to `CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm` as you are not casting anything there.
- `getAllCellInfo();` returns a List. You must first choose one element in that list and work with it. Do this by writing `CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)TM.getAllCellInfo().get(0);` I used 0 as an example, you will first need to check the list's size then choose a CellInfo Object.

Comment: (ClassName) means you are casting one object as something else. Your variable `cellinfogsm` is new and has not been called, so you must not have any brackets around CellInfoGsm. It's a syntax thing. This link will explain objects and casting. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html